# Stop process without close windows form in cs

Tags: c#, wpf

What should i do to stop a wpf program? i don't want to close windows form. i just want to stop (continue code process) and die with no windows form close (die just for continue the process not for application or windows form)

Comment: This doesn't make sense! When a process stops all Windows are closed! Or do you mean: pause the process?

Answer (score -1):

i found it i can use `return;` to just not continue the codes in a function